# Extracting n number of images using a python Web Scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping and I am using python to build a **Google Images Web Scraper**. This is a snippet of my code.

```
import requests 
import os
import bs4 as bs

query = 'kittens'
url = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q='+query+'&source=lnms&tbm=isch'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

os.makedirs('new1')

imgElem = soup.select('div img') 
print(len(imgElem))

for i in range(1,len(imgElem)):
    if imgElem == []:                        #if not found print error
        print('could not find any image')

    else:
        try:
            imgUrl = imgElem[i].get('src')
            print(imgElem[i].get('src'))
            print('Downloading image %s.....' %(imgUrl))
            res = requests.get(imgUrl)
            res.raise_for_status()

        #except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema:
        except Exception as e:
        #skip if not a normal image file
            print(e)
            
        num = str(i) + ".jpg"
        imageFile = open(os.path.join('.\\new1', num),'wb')     
        #write downloaded image to hard disk
        for chunk in res.iter_content(10000):
            imageFile.write(chunk)
            
        imageFile.close()
```

len(imgElem) returns 21 for me.

I can currently only download 20 images.

Why do I get only 20 images and what would be a good way to overcome this?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the loop (don't worry about part about saving the images).

Comment: Added the full code including the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having this issue because not all the `src` attribute values in `imgEleme` are valid urls.

Try this:

```
for el in imgElem:
    print(el['src'])
```

You will see that first output line is

```
/images/branding/searchlogo/1x/googlelogo_desk_heirloom_color_150x55dp.gif
```

while all the others are valid urls. So the statement:

```
res = requests.get(imgUrl)
```

fails in that cases; hence only 20 images downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I encountered this problem of getting an invalid url for the first image and so I changed my range to range(1, len(imgElem)). I looked at the source code for the page and based on that I thought that it should not stop at 20.
Could there be any other reason for this and do you have any suggestions on how I could get more than 20 images? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Idioteche_fish That works in this case, but on other searches the invalid url may be in line 15 or whatever; you'll need a more generalized solution to handle it.

Comment: Okay, I'll look for a more generalized way to solve this. However, I was wondering if it was a Google Images issue because I get exactly 20 images no matter what query I search for in Google Images.

Comment: @Idioteche_fish Looking at the "bad" url again, it seems it's the Google logo; in that case, it will always be in the first place and it will explain why you are getting only 20 images every time. So it seems your solution will work after all!

Comment: Yeah, that explains image 1 but I'm sorry but I do not understand how that explains the 20 image cap. How can I increase this cap to say a 100 or more. 
My end goal is to ask the user for the number of images they want to collect.

Comment: @Idioteche_fish The image cap has nothing to do with the search; it's probably something that can be adjusted at the Google API level. You may actually want to post it as a separate question.